# How can I run a bat file after project has been published to folder in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I need to run a bat file after I have published my project using Visual Studio 2022. After searching the web I found that this should be able to be done by modifying the csproj file. So I added the following line to this file and run th publish command. I dont get any errors but the bat file I try to execute is not run. Is there anyone that know if this is actually supported?

```
      <Target Name="ExecuteBatAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="D:\postbuild.bat"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Why should it not be supported? The "AfterPublish" is mentioned in the docs: [Target build order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Ok but the bat file is not run so to me its not working anyway

Answer (score 0):

In mine I have `<Target Name="ExecuteBatAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">`